# Proving $(2n-1)^n + (2n)^n ≈ (2n+1)^n$

Tags: limits, proof-verification

As I do, I was messing around and I thought to myself this simple thing:

$3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$

I just thought that this is only Pythagorean triplet with sequential integers. I know that there are no others and there are no others to higher powers due to Fermat's Last Theorem. However there are many that can be approximated.

$5^3 + 6^3 = 341 ≈ 7^3$

$7^4 + 8^4 = 6479 ≈ 9^4$

$9^5 + 10^5 = 159049 ≈ 11^5$

As you can see, there is a pattern occurring in the form of:

$(2n-1)^n + (2n)^n ≈ (2n + 1)^n \{n ∈ ℤ+; n > 0\}$

It also seems the that if you rearrange the equation and take the limit at +∞:

$\lim_{n\to +\infty} { [(2n-1)^n + (2n)^n]^{1/n} - (2n + 1) } = 2ln(1 + e^{1/2}) - 2 ≈ -0.051846 $
(Calculated using Wolfram|Alpha)

Has this been noticed before; if so, is there a proof or is this the proof?

Comment: Perhaps also try moving everything to one side and using the binomial theorem. You may be able to bound the result nicely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\left(\dfrac{2n-1}{2n+1} \right)^n = \left(1 -\dfrac2{2n+1} \right)^n \sim \dfrac1e - \dfrac1{en^2} + \mathcal{O}(1/n^4)$$

$$\left(\dfrac{2n}{2n+1} \right)^n = \left(1 -\dfrac1{2n+1} \right)^n \sim \dfrac1{\sqrt{e}}$$

Hence,
$$\left(\dfrac{2n-1}{2n+1} \right)^n + \left(\dfrac{2n}{2n+1} \right)^n \sim \dfrac1e + \dfrac1{\sqrt{e}} \approx 0.97441$$

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize I could do it that way. So just taking the series at n=∞ and then if n = ∞ (limit as n->∞), the other terms disappear.

e^-1 + e^-0.5 ≈ 1

Comment: One small note: this _does_ mean that the error is on the order of $C\cdot(2n+1)^n$, just with a relatively small $C$ - that is, there's no cancellation of terms that makes it closer than you might 'expect' (that is, it's not true that $(2n-1)^n+(2n)^n-(2n+1)^n\in o\left((2n+1)^n\right)$ ).

Comment: A short remark on that last approximation: $\begin{align}e\simeq2.718\\\varphi\simeq1.618\end{align}\iff e\simeq\varphi+1=\varphi^2\iff\sqrt e\simeq\varphi$. But since $\displaystyle\frac1\varphi+\frac1{\varphi^2}=\frac1\varphi+\frac1{\varphi+1}=1$ $\displaystyle\iff\frac1e+\frac1{\sqrt e}\simeq1$. In particular, $\displaystyle\frac1e+\frac1{\sqrt e}+\frac1{39}\simeq1^{^+}$, with an error of about $5\cdot10^{-5}$.